# Tags [captcha] and [recaptcha] – married or single?

Tags: support, tags

**UPDATE:** The combination tag [captcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha) and tag [recaptcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) is not in use at present.

---

Very similar in concept to [Tags [gmail] and [email] – married or single?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/tags-gmail-and-email-married-or-single) which does not so far have an Answer to serve as a guide.

[captcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha) without [recaptcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) 2 Open Qs, 1 follower, no Usage guide.

[recaptcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) without [captcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha) 3 Open Qs, 0 follower, Usage guide:

> For questions specifically about the reCAPTCHA service by Google.

[captcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha)[recaptcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) 1 Open Q: [Why is ReCaptcha sometimes really easy and sometimes really hard?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60817/why-is-recaptcha-sometimes-really-easy-and-sometimes-really-hard)

When should the above both be applied to a Q rather than one **or** the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a question is about reCAPTCHA, it should simply be tagged with [recaptcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha). There's no need to tag with [captcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha) as well.

[captcha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha) would seem to be a meta tag, as it has no context without other tags. It can probably be removed or, possibly, replaced with [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security).